# Array_slice with return of sliced elements

Tags: php, arrays, slice

I'm removing a set of elements with array slice, from e certain offset to the end.

How can I get the elements that were removed, in a different array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to use `array_slice` twice:

```
$begin = array_slice($array, 0, 5);
$end = array_slice($array, 5);
```

Now `$begin` contains the first 5 elements of `$array`, and `$end` contains the rest.

Answer (score 0):

`array_slice` will return an array containing the elements that were removed. You can also use `array_diff` to find the elements that were not removed.

```
$original = array('1','2','3','4','5');
$sliced = array_slice($original,1); // 2, 3, 4, 5
$diff = array_diff($original,$sliced); // 1
```

Comment: It won't work if the array contains equal values like  `array('1', '1', '1', '1')`.